# How to make a checkbox selected when searching from database

Tags: c#

i created a form,containing fields emloyeeid,employeename,age...,and a checkbox.
When searching using employeeid ,i want to the checkbox selected/deselected according to the value saved in the database(the checkbox field in database is boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on your db access approach, one example.

```
 checkbox1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(ordinal);
```